# Get loss and accuracy graphic based on saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I forgot to save the history during training (I just call the `model.fit()` directly without save the return into variable), luckily I saved the model every epoch into `unet_model.h5`.

So how do I show loss and accuracy based on saved model?
You need to know that I'm using train and test generator.

```
#@markdown 6. Mendefinisikan generator data untuk *training* dan *testing*.
# Ini dilakukan karena data yang digunakan adalah data gambar agar dapat masuk ke neuron.

def train_generator(images_path, labels_path, batch_size, image_size):
  image_paths = [os.path.join(images_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(images_path)]
  label_paths = [os.path.join(labels_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(labels_path)]
  assert len(image_paths) == len(label_paths)

  while True:
    indices = np.random.choice(len(image_paths), batch_size)
    batch_images = []
    batch_labels = []

    for i in indices:
      image_path = image_paths[i]
      label_path = label_paths[i]

      image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      image = cv2.resize(image, image_size)
      image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.

      label = cv2.imread(label_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      label = cv2.resize(label, image_size)
      label = label.astype(np.float32) / 255.
      label[label > 0.5] = 1.0
      label[label <= 0.5] = 0.0

      batch_images.append(np.expand_dims(image, axis=2))
      batch_labels.append(np.expand_dims(label, axis=2))

    yield np.array(batch_images), np.array(batch_labels)

def test_generator(images_path, labels_path, image_size):
  image_paths = sorted([os.path.join(images_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(images_path)])
  label_paths = sorted([os.path.join(labels_path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(labels_path)])
  assert len(image_paths) == len(label_paths)

  images = []
  labels = []
  for i in range(len(image_paths)):
    image_path = image_paths[i]
    label_path = label_paths[i]

    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, image_size)
    image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.

    label = cv2.imread(label_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    label = cv2.resize(label, image_size)
    label = label.astype(np.float32) / 255.
    label[label > 0.5] = 1.0
    label[label <= 0.5] = 0.0

    images.append(np.expand_dims(image, axis=2))
    labels.append(np.expand_dims(label, axis=2))

  return np.array(images), np.array(labels)
```

So how do I show the loss and accuracy graphic of training/testing?

ChatGPT answer give me answer to train few epochs from saved model then show the graph which it's useless since it didn't give the real graphic start from epoch 0.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Ikhwan Perwira, Loss and accuracy of the model generates at the time of model training. As you have saved the model then you can try loading back the model (`reloaded_model = model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`, and retrain with same train and test data while assigning to history variable (`history = reloaded_model.fit(..)`) to get the loss and accuracy metrics logged and can plot these loss,metrics. Please check this replicated code [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/fd0d80b8a67482467c0647b4c5e9c0b6/76024117.ipynb) for your reference.